# Writing a resume with no job experience?

Tags: resume

I have no job experience whatsoever. How should I write such on a resume?

Comment: How old are you? School, uni? No part time jobs? No Hobbies?

Comment: @EdHeal I'm in university. No part time jobs to speak of but hobbies and volunteer work, some of which related to my field.

Comment: So I guess in late teens. Focus on your education (people would be expect to not have any/little work experience). Add hobbies. You mention volunteer work. Add that. You should be fine. One would expect your CV to be about a page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What to include in a graduate's resume with zero employment history?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18648/what-to-include-in-a-graduates-resume-with-zero-employment-history)

Answer (score 4):

Writing your very first resume takes some creativity.  Include your volunteer experience (if any), clubs you've been part of, and marketable skills you've developed.  Whatever you've done in your non-professional life that could indicate to a company that you are a good hire is fair game.  People hiring for intern/entry level positions may be willing to give you a shot with no work experience so long as you are able to sell yourself as the kind of person they want in their organization.

Answer (score 1):

This is an outline for your first CV

1. Personal details (name, address, phone number etc). Perhaps format this to take up a little space
   2, Personal profile: Summary of skills and aspirations. This can be about two paragraphs.
2. As just out of University put education first - High school (Qualifications etc.). University - Mention relevant courses for the job. Dissertations/projects done. Write one or two paragraphs here at least. Can get another couple of paragraphs on the subjects that you enjoyed the most.
3. Work experience - you mention voluntary work. Here is another couple of paragraphs. Make it relevant to the job/work environment. Have a highlight here.
4. Another paragraph on a hobby.
5. Say references are available on request.

Make sure the spelling is correct. Make sure the grammar is correct.

You should not go too far wrong.

Remember the CV is the thing to but your foot in the door for an interview. When that door knocks - do the following

1. Read as much as you can about the company/industry/job role.
2. Read up on current events
3. make sure you know before the interview where you are going to. Have a scouting and find a coffee shop around the corner. Aim to get there 1/2 before the interview. Walk in 5 mins before the appointment. Punctuational but not too early
4. Do not worry if the 1st few interviews you do not get a job. Just learn from them.

After the interview - perhaps send a polite email saying thank you.

Also: When going to an interview - everybody can have feedback - that includes the person emptying the bins in the lobby along with the receptionist.

Comment: It's a bit over the top but I like to do personalized CVs I did this when I started spamming out my CVs, and it got me a fair amount of interview, so yes 100% agree with reading about the interview, trust me you'll leave a great impression on the recruiter

Comment: Why do you recommend not to arrive too early? For most interviews I've attended, I have arrived even 30 minutes early and no one commented on that. Sometimes you just need to wait in the lobby until they become available from a previous meeting. A good moment to collect your thoughts and relax.

Comment: Do that at the coffee shop around the corner. It does put people under pressure if you arrive very early.