# What things to consider while writing resume and cover letter with no experience?

Tags: job-search, resume, job-offer, hiring-process, cover-letter

I am about to start applying for jobs in IT as Web developer. I am pretty new to it. I have never applied for job in my life. Moreover, I have never work before anywhere including IT. I do have Masters degree in IT and I am 23 (if that helps) (soon graduating).

I did made 2 good projects that basically include people being able to signup/login and can post stuff there and each user can have a look at their profile as in what they posted and others can see all the posts (as that's how most website works)

2. I have fetched data from Zomato API and designed the website well and it has all the restaurant's and user can even search up specific restaurants.

The bottom ones are not too great (as I think they are too basic or easy to do).

3. To-do list - Here people can create a list of things they want to do and it gets saved on their local device if they close the tab and open it later and it shows the current temperature of their location.
4. A Wordpress website - Here it shows all the restaurant's in whole Australia including near by tourist places close to restaurant's.

My question is (I would prefer answer from people who are HR although others can share their opinion as well) Is this more than enough to be able to get a job as Web developer if I add those things in my resume or is there anything someone would like to add so I can land a job with those projects?

Also, any recommendation on how to write a cover letter as I have never had a job before? What are specific things HR wants in cover letter or care about?

I know this might be a very basic question and is a broad question, but I am trying to give an idea of my projects as I didn't have any job before, so if it helps to answer. But, I believe those are the two things HR sees first (Resume and Cover letter) so it does makes the first impression. Please feel free to add anything that would be helpful. If more details is needed please let me know.

Comment: @gnat It does not answer my question since I do have projects that I can show my ability to work with different programming languages. But that guy who asked this questions has none of it. Hence, my question is a bit different.

Comment: if you believe that this difference is very important then exactly what you metion was also asked and answered before in another question: [What to include in a graduate's resume with zero employment history?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/18648/168)

Comment: @gnat I understand. What I am trying to say is it only answer some of my question, not all of it. Moreover, I have projects listed so it still does not count as 0 experience, cause you show your skills using personal projects. That being said, my resume can look a lot different then what is mentioned in that answer. It's why I said it's a lot different still to what I am asking. I don't have professional experience, but do have some good projects.

Comment: Keep your resume **simple, standard and clear**. Your experience is fine for a starter.  Simply list the four items. Keep each item  **simple, standard and clear**. People only glance at resumes.

Comment: Confirming the duplicate as "a bit different" doesn't make your question materially different. The linked question doesn't appear to mention a lack of projects. If the answers aren't great, you might want to start a bounty on that question to attract higher quality answers.

Comment: @Fattie And for the age of 28-30 years old is this a good luggage?

Answer (score -1):

You can make a tag cloud of all your skills, this could be complemented with a graph over how well you know each skill in particular. For an example c# 4 star and Java 3 stars.

It helps them see if you have the right profile.

One advice would to also use a good template and not just the regular white and black. I once made my Resume in "Dark-mode" which really piqued the interest in the developers.
https://www.canva.com/

I would also recommend just googling expert advice because there are alot of ways to improve your chances.

Another thing would be taking their "wants" and commenting how you stack up against each, So if they want php you can say that you´ve never worked with it but you know that it is similar to ASP and that you think you would have have an easy time picking up php because they work in the same way. Doing this for each thing they ask for in the ad gives them a better understanding of your knowledge and how much it will take from them to train you.

I would mention the projects but only alittle, That way they can ask you about it at the interview. The more vague the better.

Comment: Could you please clarify what the links is about "canva.com"?

Comment: Also, If I don't say a little bit about my project how would they know If I am suitable for the interview or not? As I have added the links to my website along with a line description on my portfolio including one image of website.

Comment: Adding links is a great idea.I would also recommend applying for atleast 20-50 jobs if you haven´t already. Even remote ones, Simply because of pure statistics. And the more you apply the more you improve your own application process. You tend to figure out more what to present to an employeer. Canva.com Is a website where you can make designs, I would recommend it for making a colourful CV.

Comment: Please take care to spell "piqued" correctly.

Comment: I apologize, English is not my native language :)